# In which way Actionscript 3 reference can be downloaded?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder, flash-builder

I have used Flash Builder 4 built-in help viewer, and I'm pretty sure there was an option to download the reference. But I have once selected "view help in browser", and from then I 
can't see an option to come back and use the help viewer as before, and thus I can't find
the reference download option.

btw, the reference is available online at:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: @sberry2A: You may think whether you have the knowledge for posting such a comment, or whether it is rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the Adobe Help application, go into preferences, select General Settings, and change the preference from "Open Help in Browser" to "Open Community Help Application".  Hope that helps.

Comment: Wade: I have managed out to open the built-in help browser, but there is no 'Preferences' option. And on the flash builder window, going to help-> flash builder help - this open my browser directly. To what you refer by 'adobe help application'?

Comment: got it. The path for adobe help application is by default at:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Help\Adobe Help.exe